# Insight into basic group calling architecture in GStreamer using Webrtcbin

Tags: gstreamer

I have a simple app that provides basic group calling (audio mixing and video compositing) in the cloud. WebRTC clients in Chrome connect; sending and receiving media.

My architecture at the moment is:

```
                --> A/V --> webrtcbin_1 -> audiomixer_1 / compositor_1 ->|
Chrome WebRTC_1                                                          |
                <-- A/V <-- webrtcbin_1 <--------------------------------v
```

```
                --> A/V --> webrtcbin_2 -> audiomixer_2 / compositor_2 ->|
Chrome WebRTC_2                                                          |
                <-- A/V <-- webrtcbin_2 <--------------------------------v
```

When `Chrome WebRTC_2` decides to join, it connects to its own `webrtcbin_2` and then sends its audio to `audiomixer_1` and its video to `compositor_1`. Likewise, `Chrome WebRTC_1` does the reverse (sends audio to `audiomixer_2` and video to `compositor_2`).

Example for Chrome WebRTC_1:

```
                                                 _____________________________
                                                |                |            ^                                                                
                                                V                v            |
                --> A/V --> webrtcbin_1 -> audiomixer_1 / compositor_1 ->|    |
Chrome WebRTC_1                                                          |    |
                <-- A/V <-- webrtcbin_1 <--------------------------------v    |
                                                                              |
                                                                              |
Chrome WebRTC_2 --> A/V --> webrtcbin_2 ------------------------------------->
```

Is this an efficient way to mix audio and video in the cloud, or could there be issues related to crossing audio/video through mixers/compositors and into opposite webrtcbins? My concern is that audio and video is crossing into audiomixers and compositors from two separate RTP streams, which could result in latency due to GStreamer attempting to A/V sync or something similar (i.e. clock syncs with the SR's or what have you).

My ultimate goal is to ensure that both WebRTC clients receive the lowest latency output from the cloud as they can. Synchronization amongst them isn't required.